# Close/Unpack Object "matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg"

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is code that takes a figure and displays it on a Tkinter window. How do I unpack/delete "canvas" from the GUI?

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

    def plot(x, y):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax1.plot(x,y)
        return fig

    plt = plot(1,1)
    root = Tk()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

Comment: Typically you'd destroy the canvas's tk_widget. E.g. `canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()`.  However, if you're only trying to temporarily hide the plot, there are better ways.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to replace it with another type of canvas. So for example, my GUI displays information on a graph using matplotlib, but then uses the tkinter canvas widget to display another set of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to remove the plot and free up the parent frame/window, call `canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()`.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def main():
    fig = plot(range(10), range(10))
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    root.bind_all('<Button-1>', lambda event: remove_plot(canvas))

    root.mainloop()

def plot(x, y):
    fig = Figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    return fig

def remove_plot(canvas):
    canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()

main()
```

This only destroys the figure's tk widget. The figure still exists and could be added again, assuming it hasn't gone out of scope and been garbage collected.  (Also, the figure will be garbage collected just like any other object as we're not using the pyplot state machine.)