# Replacing an existing bar graph with a new one by deleting the old one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm new to Python. I was expecting `plt.close('all')` to remove the old graph when I clicked the button named **CHANGE DATA**. Instead, the new graph is placed beside the old graph (to its left). Additional clicks would show more graphs, but the old one is never removed.

Am I doing it all wrong or is this a limitation of using **tkinter** and **matplotlib** together?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def displ_graf(datalst):
    ff = plt.figure(figsize=(5.6,4), dpi=100)
    xx = ff.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    nn = np.arange(len(datalst))
    bb = xx.barh(nn, datalst, 0.8)
    ff.tight_layout
    cc = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ff, master=ww)
    cc.draw()
    cc.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

def graf2():
    plt.close('all')
    data2 = [64, 58, 12, 91, 49, 32, 70, 23, 35]
    displ_graf(data2)

ww = tk.Tk()
ww.geometry('700x400')
ww.state('zoomed')
butt3 = Button(ww,text=' CHANGE DATA ',command=graf2, height=1,width=15)
butt3.place(x=790, y=100)

data1 = [31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97, 93, 23]
displ_graf(data1)
ww.mainloop()
```

The image on the left shows the **initial screen** before clicking the button, and the image on the right shows the screen **after clicking** on the button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the use of `cc.get_tk_widget().destroy()` . But your code seems kinda clumsily written. So maybe check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875628/close-unpack-object-matplotlib-backends-backend-tkagg-figurecanvastkagg)

Just as an example that it works:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def displ_graf(datalst):
    ff = plt.figure(figsize=(5.6,4), dpi=100)
    xx = ff.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    nn = np.arange(len(datalst))
    bb = xx.barh(nn, datalst, 0.8)
    ff.tight_layout
    cc = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ff, master=ww)
    cc.draw()
    cc.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    return cc

def graf2():    
    data2 = [64, 58, 12, 91, 49, 32, 70, 23, 35]
    displ_graf(data2)

def destroy():
    canv.get_tk_widget().destroy()

ww = tk.Tk()
ww.geometry('700x400')
ww.state('normal')
butt3 = Button(ww,text=' CHANGE DATA ',command=graf2, height=1,width=15)
butt4 = Button(ww,text=' destroy ',command=destroy, height=1,width=15)
butt3.place(x=790, y=100)
butt4.place(x=500, y=100)

data1 = [31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97, 93, 23]
canv = displ_graf(data1)
ww.mainloop()
```

But the problem here is that a new instance of cc is created each time you run `displ_graph`

Comment: I moved `canv.get_tk_widget().destroy()` into the first line of **graf2** then added `global canv` before it and changed the last line to `canv = displ_graf(data2)` and it no longer adds a graph on the left during the second click or succeeding clicks. Initially, only the first click replaced the old graph.